# VLC on Android streaming

Tags: android, networking, streaming, vlc

I am using Wowza stream content to an Android device using VLC.

When the connection between the Android device running VLC is lost, the screen freezes as expected, and the video is restored with the connection is restored.  However, the second time the connection is lost, VLC stops the stream, and I would need to select the stream path for it to begin playing again.

I set the cache to 25 seconds, but see nothing on number of attempts, or time to wait before giving up on the stream.  The ideal behaviour is to always wait until the connection is resorted without intervention, even if the time between attempts grows the longer the network connection is lost.

Where can I set VLC on android to always wait for a stream, and never give up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue .you experience a deadlock in `libvlc`. that happens when you try to play and stop nearly simultaneously or something like that. the problem is that the input thread does not finish.this is due to race
conditions after calls to `vlc_object_alive()`.

this patch can help you :

https://github.com/rom1v/vlc-udp-deadlock/